# undefined method `action_mailer' during Capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, capistrano, bundler

I'm having this error message come up during Capistrano deployment. It implies to me that something's wrong with Rails being installed or something? Rails is *not* currently installed on the server side, but it's in my Gemfile (and my Gemfile.lock), so I'm assuming it should be installed during the `bundle install` command that gets executed before this line.

The actual command that's giving the error is:

`bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile`

I guess the problem is just that Rails is not being installed during the bundle install. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:** Rails appears to be installing correctly via the `bundle install` command. If I check out the directory `.../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems`, I can see action mailer in there.

**UPDATE 2:** Running the command `rake assets:precompile` actually fails locally as well, so this doesn't have anything to do with Capistrano it would appear. Now I just have to figure out why the `config` object doesn't know anything about action mailer?

**UPDATE 3:** Hot on the trail. It looks like my installed version of actionmailer is 0.6.1 (?!), meanwhile all the rest of my Rails stuff is up at 3.2.9. `bundle update` refuses to update actionmailer past this version. I'm going to remove all of my gems and start fresh.

**UPDATE 4:** Deleted my entire gemset using `rvm gemset empty`. Then tried to run bundle again, and **again** it tries to get actionmailer 0.6.1. I think something is screwed up with bundler or something...

Comment: Are you running as root on the server side?

Comment: I'm running as a user that is a member of the `sudo` group on a Unix machine. So no, not running as root, but I should have permission. It's able to create directories and stuff in the earlier stages...

Comment: Also try deleting your Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I had removed a dependency upon a *specific* version of Rails in my Gemfile. I just had `gem "rails"` in there. That seemed to completely botch the dependency calculations, because it was getting super-old versions of action mailer rather than getting a consistent version from all gems. Guess it's a bad idea to not specify an exact Rails version. Yikes!

Answer (score 1):

@aardvarkk,

Thanks for posting this issue, I was having the same error with my installation of Rails 4.0.0 and the error was preventing me from running my rails server

This is while I'm trying to follow the Hartl Tutorial for RoR.

I added `gem "rails", '4.0.0'` to my gem file and now I'm able to run my rails server.

Thank you